# How can I turn off my android smartPhone screen?

Tags: android

How can I turn off my android SmartPhone screen programmatically?
I tried with the code below, it doesn't work, it just locks the screen but does not "switch off" the screen.
The method goToSleep have been Removed. https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/21/changes/android.os.PowerManager.html

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
 PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
 wl.acquire();
   ..screen will stay on during this section..
 wl.release();
```

Comment: Regarding your edit: have you looked at *all* the answers in the linked post? There are more than 2 methods presented.

Answer (score 0):

Set permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK">
```

Here is the code

```
PowerManager manager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
manager.goToSleep(int amountOfTime);
```

Comment: The method goToSleep have been Removed. https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/21/changes/android.os.PowerManager.html